# nodejs application not receiving request

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm trying to run a nodejs rest api application on port 5000 while another nodejs rest api already running on another port 8080. After starting the application on port 5000. Application on port 8080 is running at it is as early, but application on port 5000 is not receiving any requests and my client got time out all the time. I'm creating https server for both of the case. Why this is happening.

I'm running nginx server.

My app code :

```
const os = require('os');
var cluster = require('cluster');

const numCPUs = os.cpus().length;


 if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log('Master '+process.pid+' is running');

  // Fork workers.
 for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
  cluster.fork();
 }

 cluster.on('error', function(worker){
    console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died..');
    cluster.fork();
 });

 cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal){
  console.log('Worker ' + worker.id + ' died..');
  cluster.fork();
 });

} else {
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const express    = require('express');        // call express
const app        = express();  
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // call body-parser
const addData = require('./dbhandler/addData');
const getData = require('./dbhandler/getData');
const updateData = require('./dbhandler/updateData');
const dbhandler = require('./dbhandler/dbhandler');
const log4js = require('log4js');
const request = require('request');
const redis = require('redis');

'use strict';
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

log4js.configure({
  "appenders": [ {
    "type": "dateFile",
    "filename": "./logs/apierrorlogs.log",
    "pattern": "-yyyy-MM-dd",
    "alwaysIncludePattern": false,
    "category" : "apilogs",
    "backup" : 3,
    "compress" : true
  } ]
});

var logger = log4js.getLogger("apilogs");
logger.setLevel('ERROR');

console.log('Worker '+process.pid+' started');

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  logger.error(err);
});


var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('./abcdef.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('./xyz.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = {key: privateKey, cert: certificate};

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const REDIS_PORT = process.env.PORT;
const redisClient = redis.createClient(REDIS_PORT);

function cache(req, res, next) {
    const key = req.url;
    // redisClient.del(key);
    redisClient.get(key , function (error, data) {
        if (error){
            console.log('error while getting data from cache for key = '+key)
            logger.error(error);
            next();
        } else if (data != null) {
            console.log('data is present in cache for key = '+key);
            res.send(JSON.parse(data));
        } else {
            console.log('data is not present in cache for key = '+key);
            next();
        }
    });
}

function checkUser(req,res){
    var success;
    try {
        var userExist;
        console.log("Route = /checkuser/:userEmail, userEmail = "+req.params.userEmail);
        getData.checkUserEmail(req.params.userEmail,function(error, results, fields){
            if (!error){
                if (results.length == 0) {
                    success = 1;
                    datasets = { 
                        "userExist" : 0
                    }
                    res.json({"success" : success, "datasets" : datasets});
                } else {
                    var userId = results[0]['user_id'];
                    getData.getMappedUserId(userId,0,function(error,results,fields){
                        if (!error) {
                            var userId = results[0]['id'];
                            getData.getUserInterests(userId, function(error, results, fields){
                                if (!error) {
                                    success = 1;
                                    datasets = {
                                        "userExist" : 1,
                                        "userId" : userId, 
                                        "interest" : results.length
                                    }
                                    res.json({"success" : success, "datasets" : datasets});
                                } else {
                                    logger.error("Route = /checkuser/, error = "+error);
                                    success = 0;
                                    res.json({"success" : success});
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            logger.error("Route = /checkuser/:userEmail, error = "+error);
                            success = 0;
                            res.json({"success" : success});
                        }
                    });
                }
            } else{
                logger.error("Route = /checkuser/:userEmail, error = "+error);
                success = 0;
                res.json({"success" : success});
            }
        });
    } catch (error){
        logger.error("Route = /checkuser/:userEmail, error = "+error);
        success = 0;
        res.json({"success" : success});
    }
}

router.get('/checkuser/:userEmail', checkUser);

app.use('/api/v1', router);

var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);
httpsServer.listen(port);

Process output in my terminal :
sasuke@example.com:~$ ps aux | grep node
sasuke    2140 37.3  3.3 1114124 270980 pts/0  Rl+  09:13  48:48 node 
/usr/bin/pm2 monit
sasuke    7031  0.1  0.3 915484 30972 ?        Ssl  10:31   0:05 node 
/home/sasuke/restapiv3/app-server-v3.js     
sasuke    7042  0.0  0.5 941300 45920 ?        Sl   10:31   0:03 node 
/home/sasuke/restapiv3/app-server-v3.js                
sasuke    7048  0.0  0.5 939936 46864 ?        Sl   10:31   0:03 node 
/home/sasuke/restapiv3/app-server-v3.js                
sasuke    7054  0.0  0.5 940824 47520 ?        Sl   10:31   0:03 node 
/home/sasuke/restapiv3/app-server-v3.js                
sasuke    7055  0.0  0.5 941320 45856 ?        Sl   10:31   0:03 node 
/home/sasuke/restapiv3/app-server-v3.js                
sasuke    8561  0.0  0.0  12008  2188 pts/4    S+   11:24   0:00 grep -
-color=auto node
sasuke   30629  0.2  0.4 922344 35524 ?        Ssl  Jul03  13:06 node 
/home/sasuke/restapi/app.js                 
sasuke   30639  0.3  1.1 1264668 93944 ?       Sl   Jul03  20:43 node 
/home/sasuke/restapi/app.js                            
sasuke   30645  0.3  1.0 1262676 89328 ?       Sl   Jul03  20:43 node 
/home/sasuke/restapi/app.js                            
sasuke   30651  0.3  1.1 1265152 92096 ?       Sl   Jul03  20:37 node 
/home/sasuke/restapi/app.js                            
sasuke   30652  0.3  1.0 1264576 89852 ?       Sl   Jul03  20:48 node 
/home/sasuke/restapi/app.js`
```

My nginx configuration file :

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 8096;
    multi_accept on;
}

worker_rlimit_nofile 40000;

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 45;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # buffer optimizations
    client_body_buffer_size 10K;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    access_log off;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
 }
```

Comment: Usually, if both the node servers are running on a different port, it doesn't conflict with each other. However, it might be the issue with your server code running on 5000 port. Please do mention your code to help us figure out the issue.

Comment: Right, and show the nginx config as well please.  Also, are you certain it's not running on port 5000? Have you received errors when starting it and do you not see it when you look at your running processes?

Comment: @Sravan updated my code please check it.

Comment: @Paul netstat -tulpen show this
`tcp6       0      0 :::5000                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       18193606    7031/app-server-v3.

tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      1000       16397086    30629/app.js`

Comment: So it looks like it's running.  Are you hitting it through the NGINX endpoint or have you tried just hitting it through localhost:5000?

Comment: What is the role of nginx here ? are you back proxying or directly running, if back proxying please share nginx config file. Else please start both servers and do a `ps aux | grep node` in a new terminal and share output here

Comment: @Paul I'm calling like this 
`https://example.com:5000/api/v1/checkuser/xyz@example.com `

Comment: Ok, so again try calling it directly on localhost instead of going through NGINX, and if it works then you at least know the problem is with your NGINX configuration

Comment: @Paul I have uploaded my nginx config file please go through it.

Comment: @Paul the problem is solved it is my fire wall which is causing the problem.thanks